# SQL Server Express and C# : Database Charting

Tags: c#, sql, database, charts

I am trying to link my SQL Server Express database to a chart in a c# application. I am trying to extract the age of some employees to display them in a bar char. Here is my code

```
string constring = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Michael\\Downloads\\Employee\\Employee\\Employee\\EmployeeDetails.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Initial Catalog=Employee";

SqlConnection conDatabase = new SqlConnection(constring);
SqlCommand cmdDatabase = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee;", conDatabase);
SqlDataReader myReader;

try{
    conDatabase.Open();
    myReader=cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

    while(myReader.Read())
    {
        this.chart1.Series["Age"].Points.AddXY(myReader.GetString("FirstName"), myReader.GetInt32("Age"));
    }
}
```

When I compile my program, I get 4 error messages, which relate to this line:

```
(myReader.GetString("FirstName"), myReader.GetInt32("Age"))
```

The error messages are:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)' has some invalid arguments
>   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int' 
>   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetInt32(int)' has some invalid arguments
>   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

The SQL Server Express database uses `VARCHAR` for `FirstName` and `INT` for `Age`

what have i done wrong?

Comment: Ok so i have adapted the code and it works, but it only shows the first person in the database, how do i show all the employees?

Comment: Solved it used, a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IDataReader`'s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `.Get*` methods only take the index of the column to be accessed, not the column name.

So instead of

```
myReader.GetString("FirstName")
```

You'll need something like

```
myReader["FirstName"].ToString()
```

and

```
Convert.ToInt32(myReader.GetInt32("Age")))
```

If you are doing this in a tight loop, then you can cache the name : index mappings.

Answer (score 2):

> Error 1 The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)' has some invalid
>   arguments

[`DbDataReader.GetString` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes argument as an `int`, not `string`.

> Gets the value of the **specified column** as an instance of String.

```
public abstract string GetString(
    int ordinal
)
```

Use this method with what is the *zero-based* column ordinal of your `FirstName` and `Age` columns.

> Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

There is no implicit conversation from `string` to `int`. You get this error actually because `myReader.GetString("FirstName")` method returns `string` but your `AddXY()` method probably except `int` as a first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you should use GetString(0) or GetString(1) or GetString(2)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
try{
    conDatabase.Open();
    myReader=cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

    chart1.DataSource = myReader;

    chart1.Series["Age"].XValueMember = "FirstName";
    chart1.Series["Age"].YValueMembers = "Age";

    chart1.DataBind(); 
}
```

Comment: I have tried your method, but get an error message, object reference is not set to an instance of an object?

Comment: `chart1` may not be initialized.